# How can I upper case the letter with an even index in a string

Tags: python, python-3.x, string

Here is my thought: I want to create new empty string (newst), and add letters in the tested string (st) one by one by testing and upper or lower case the letter depends on the even or odd index.

Below is my code:

```py
def myfunc(st):
    newst = ''
    for i in st:
        if st.index(i) %2 == 0:
            newst = newst + i.upper()
        else:
            newst = newst + i.lower()
    return newst
```

When I test the code:

```
myfunc('bbAA')
```

I got:
'BBAA'

Can anyone help me to explain why I got the incorrect result?
Thank you

Answer (score 2):

Don't use `.index` in a loop to find the index of the current value; it finds the index of the *first occurrence* of that value, not necessarily the occurrence you're currently looking at. Iterate using `enumerate` to get both the index and value together:

```py
def myfunc(st):
    newst = ''
    for index, char in enumerate(st):
        if index % 2 == 0:
            newst = newst + char.upper()
        else:
            newst = newst + char.lower()
    return newst
```

Similar solution using `join` and a comprehension:

```py
def myfunc(st):
    return ''.join(
        char.upper() if index % 2 == 0 else char.lower()
        for index, char in enumerate(st)
    )
```

Answer (score 1):

`st.index(i)` is returning the first index that has that character, so `bbAA` finds the index of the first `b` for *both* the first and second `b`. It's also highly inefficient, since it needs to perform a linear search for each character.

It's an easy fix though; [the `enumerate` function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate) will give you the index along with the value for free:

```
def myfunc(st):
    newst = ''
    for i, char in enumerate(st):
        if i % 2 == 0:
            newst += char.upper()
        else:
            newst += char.lower()
    return newst
```

Note that this does perform a decent amount of moderately expensive math for no reason (you're just alternating after all). One way to avoid it would be to have [`itertools.cycle`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.cycle) switch back and forth between `upper` and `lower` for you:

```
from itertools import cycle

def myfunc(st):
    newst = ''
    for char, op in zip(st, cycle((str.upper, str.lower))):
        newst += op(char)
    return newst
```

Note that while CPython will handle repeated `str` appends relatively efficiently, it's only an implementation detail that you can't rely on. A more portable way to do this efficiently might be to use a `list` comprehension or generator expression and `join` it:

```
def myfunc(st):
    return ''.join([op(char) for char, op in zip(st, cycle((str.upper, str.lower)))])
```

Answer (score 0):

`string.index` returns the first position where the letter you are searching is found, you should use `enumerate` to get the letter and its index

```
def myfunc(st):
    newst = ''
    for index,alpha in enumerate(st):
        if index %2 == 0:
            newst = newst + alpha.upper()
        else:
            newst = newst + alpha.lower()
    return newst


print (    myfunc("aaaBBB"))
```

And output is:

> $ python3 hack07.py
>
> AaAbBb

Answer (score 0):

Why not use `str.join` and a comprehension:

```
def myfunc(st):
    return ''.join(s.lower() if i % 2 else s.upper() for i , s in enumerate(st))

>>> myfunc('aaBB')
AbAb
```